# Blue Screen System Crash Windows 7 32/bit Can´t boot system

Tags: windows-7, crash, bsod

I am using an Acer Laptop 5720 - O/S Windows 7/32 bit. A Windows update was running and was at around Step 2 in Progress when the Laptop power button was pressed and the Laptop switched off - BLUE SCREAM!!!! - and now the Laptop will not re-boot. The black Screen appears with 2 modes: Repair Mode or Start Windows As Normal mode. Repair mode is the Default and the Computer scans itself and a Grey box appears but there is no error Information to Report. The Screen then Returns to black and cycles between the 2 modes with no Progress being made. The only Thing to do is to power off the Laptop. Is there a solution to this Problem or has my hard drive now been rendered irreperable? The BSCOD is only visible for around a second and I cannot view the error Messages for Long enough to note them. However I can Access the BIOS view. Any advice would be greatly appreciated: BlueSCREAM.

Comment: Any information about which update it was installing?

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly - unfortunately I don´t know what it was downloading re´ the scheduled Windows Update install but it was stage 2 of 10 when it was interrupted and powered off yesterday.

Comment: Do you have a Windows 7 installation disc? If so: [How to Roll Back or Uninstall a Problematic Windows Update](http://www.howtogeek.com/206271/how-to-roll-back-or-uninstall-a-problematic-windows-update/) and see the "Alternative: Use System Restore" section. If you note down the steps you take and it works, then you can write it as answer to your question here.

Comment: Thank you. I bought the Laptop some years ago and don´t have the original Installation disc. It was upgraded from Vista to Windows 7 by a PC shop but they didn´t give me the Installation disc.

Comment: However, all the Responses I am getting here are much appreciated and possibly I will find a solution if enough People respond with different potential Solutions, so thank you all very much.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikey that the HDD is actually dead, much more likely that the OS doesn't know what to do.

Can you get into safe mode? Or to a place where you can do a return to a previous restore point?

If not, options are limited at this point but you could try doing a system reset of Windows as you've already tried a repair. This should reset your computer back to a working state and retain your data though your software installs will be lost.

UPDATE: Bad_System_Config_INFO with a code of 0x74 means that Windows registry is corrupt. Recommended "fixes" are to reinstall the OS or reset from a previously created recovery disk. Since you cannot get into the Windows startup options, you now have very few choices.

Comment: Julian your answer seems a good bet. The black Screen appears quickly after a momentary Flash of blue Screen, then cyles between safe mode and normal start. How Do I return to a previous rest´ Point or initiate a System re-set? I´ve recording Software on the C drive plus info on the D drive and saved Folders on the Desktop. If I could find a System R. Point that might work but am not sure how when the device isn´t even booting. Where do I look if there´s no Desktop or Icons to click on? All I get is the Flash of blue Screen, then the black one - but I can Access the Bios I think.

Comment: You need access to another machine to create something you can boot from. Either a cd/dvd if you have a suitable drive or a bootable USB stick assuming your BIOS is new enough (it probably will be). Then you need to create a windows emergency boot disk, Google will show you ways to create that. Then you should be able to start getting access to your drive again.

Comment: Thank you Julian, my Laptop is now in a PC repair shop and I won´t know more for at least another day if the hard drive has permanent/unfixable Errors (?) As soon as I know the Situation with it I will re-post here. Again, my sincere thanks for your advice and Kind help. (ditto all other respondents).

Comment: If it is not possible to Access a restore Point, is it still possible to get the operating System to start up by some other method from another Computer with Windows 7? The actual drive is not damaged, its an o/s boot up Problem. And is there some way to freeze the Blue Screen so that I can read the error Messages? It only appears for a second and I know other users have had this same issue. Thanks again.

Comment: Not possible I'm afraid. Though it may be that Windows has written a dump file but I suspect not from the description. You can access the HDD by attaching to another PC but not to access the running drive unless the OS starts (though some pro-level PC's have remote support capabilities when the OS is dead but you need an enterprise infrastructure to access such things). You could try videoing the screen as it boots which might allow you to see the error (slow-mo playback).

Comment: I have taken a photo of the Blue Screen: Messages as follows:

Comment: Bad_System_Config_INFO

Comment: Stop: 0x000000074                                                                 (0x00000002, 0x8DC3ABA8, 0x00000002,                                       0xC000014c)

Comment: These are the only coded messages on the BlueScreen. If I press F8 before the Black Microsoft splash screen appears, the laptop emits a series of loud continuous beeps.

Comment: Please see my update.